# Publishing angular-cli component library to npm or like

Tags: console, angular.js, library, typescript

I've found a lot of blog posts that seem to suggest publishing a library TypeScript (as source) and all to npm or to a private repository. It feels like we should be doing some transpiling first and then publishing only something that is ready to consume.

**Can you critique my approach for publishing a angular-cli+angular(4) components library to npm or like?**

## Context

Multiple angular front-end SPA's that may have common components i.e. a navigation bar. These common components could be published as a library including the navigation bar to npm or a privately scoped npm repository for use by the various front-end apps.

The common components could be developed in a project using angular-cli, angular(4).

## Approach

1. Create `tsconfig.aot.json` which inherits from `tsconfig.json` so that we can aot transpile the project back to `es5`

   - Ensure that metadata and index files are included/emitted
   - Ensure the `src/.npmignore` files are in place to include/exclude files already excluded by the `.gitignore`
2. When the tests pass with `ng test`, `ng e2e`, `ng lint`, and `ng build` as described in the `.travis.yml`

   - `npm version patch` (or `major` etc.)
   - `git push` + `git push --tags`
3. When the tag passes on CI

   - `ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json` which will create the distribution
   - `npm publish`

## Code

The code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-widgets/tree/0acd3263235c7b03540ea8f7677de330918a554d)

### Referenced files

#### tsconfig.aot.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/app/app.module.ts",
    "src/main-aot.ts",
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./dist/aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : false
  }
}
```

#### tsconfig.aot.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### src/.npmignore

```
*.ts
!*.d.ts
.npmignore
```

#### .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
dist: trusty
node_js:
  - 6.1
sudo: required
addons:
apt:
  sources:
    - google-chrome
  packages:
    - google-chrome-stable
    - google-chrome-beta
before_install:
  - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
install:
  - npm install
  - npm install codecov
script:
  - npm run ng test -- --single-run=true --browsers Chrome --code-coverage
  - ./node_modules/codecov/bin/codecov
  - npm run ng e2e
  - npm run ng lint
  - npm run ng build
  - npm run package
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, Be sure to embed the code you want reviewed in the question itself; you can leave supporting, but non-essential, code in links to other sites.

Comment: @StephenRauch left helpful feedback. Thank you! Could the down voter please also help me improve my review question?

Comment: If the downvote was before you revised, I would guess that was the reason.  But +1 from me. Hope you get some quality reviews.

Comment: Hi Arran, have you modified anything in the process you described above?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko: Mostly the same. I did get the process working pretty well. [working commit][https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-widgets/tree/4883d741b740ea3ec33ba7f7e46c30af9a98eed2] that is more complicated than I like. If I don't get a better answer I'll probably post the details of this as the answer. At the time of the comment the build was broken because of dependency change.